# Matplotlib in Non-Blocking Mode?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to display different data sets depending on user input.
I was trying the following peace of example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = int(raw_input())

X = []
Y = []

for i in range(N):
    X.append(np.linspace(0,10,11))
    Y.append( np.random.randn(11) )




def plotData(x, y):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)

    plt.show(block=False)

plotNumb = int(raw_input('Which plot should I display for you [integer from 0 to ' + str(N-1) + ']? '))

plotData(X[plotNumb],Y[plotNumb])

keepGoing = True
while keepGoing:
    plotNumb = int(raw_input('Can I show you another one IN ADDITION [integer from 0 to ' + str(N-1) + ']? '))
    plotData(X[plotNumb],Y[plotNumb])

    keepGoing = raw_input("Do you want to keep going?")
    if keepGoing == "Yes":
        keepGoing = True
    else:
        keepGoing = False
```

The problem is, that the data is not shown, as you can see in the figure:

[image]

Is there a way to get this thing to work without calling `show()` after both inputs? I also do not want to keep track on which windows the user already closed.

Does anyone have any good suggestions?

**EDIT:** As far as I can see from the manual there is no way to do that without workaround. However, maybe someone knows a workaround.

Comment: What about a slider? https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand what you mean. With a slider I can only change plots, if I want to add one, I do not see any other option than close the open ones and replot them all. I do not see how a slider helps? Or do I get it wrong?

Comment: Because, I guess, you simply want the plot shown in the ipython notebook? Instead of *asking* the user to type anything, let them choose from a slider as shown in the provided link. (in my opinion, asking for input is a sub-optimal way of interaction, and the culprit of typos etc)

Comment: On that I agree. However, as it is not simple to explain the real intend of the question, solving the issue above would solve my problem. This is why I said this is example code. And I really need to keep the structure of the program as it is stated in the question :(